# ForEach loop with Lambda expression in Razor code MVC 5 For List<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor, lambda

I have some list. I would like to change one or more values inside of it by using `Lambda Expressions` in Razor code especially with `ForEach` loop.

I don't know, It is possible or not, But my curiosity is more high to do with ForEach. ***I have to do this in Razor code not in the controller:***

I take a reference from this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986776/change-some-value-inside-the-listt/12986795#12986795), **BUT TRIED THE SAME SYNTAX IN RAZOR CODE:**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.months, new SelectList(Model.myList.Where(s => s.value == "1").ToList().ForEach(s => s.value = "January"), "id", "value")})
```

**Update**

Controller Code:

```
List<Digit> myList = bindMonth(12);

public static List<Digit> bindMonth(int maxvalue)
{
   List<Digit> monthList = new List<Digit>();
   maxvalue = maxvalue + 1;
   for (int i = 0; i < maxvalue; i++)
     {
         monthList.Add(new Digit(i, i.ToString()));
     }
    return monthList;
}

public class Digit
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
    public Digit(int id, string value)
    {
       this.id = id;
       this.value = value;
    }
}
```

It's throwing me *Compilation Error* in Browser.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated..!!!

Comment: What is the data type of myList? Please post the exception.

Comment: No, Got error when Page Load

Comment: new SelectList(Model.myList.Where(s => s.value == "1").Select(s => new { value = "January"}).ToList() looks like what you are trying to do ... and can you post the browser error you are getting?

Comment: Post the error you are getting.

Comment: "I take a reference from this Answer, BUT IN RAZOR CODE:" the code you posted IS razor code, what are you trying to say?

Comment: Take a reference from this Answer and Try in Razor with same syntax

Comment: Please check the update

Comment: I think you have a spurious } in your razor code. I can't see an opening {.

Comment: Yes you are right, removed it but still the same error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change some value inside the List<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986776/change-some-value-inside-the-listt)

Comment: Nope.!, It's in the `Class/Controller` file and i'm trying in `cshtml` page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an unwanted `}` at end and that's what exactly your error statement saying. Remove that and it should be like below

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.months, new SelectList(Model.myList.Where(s => s.value == "1").ToList().ForEach(s => s.value = "January"), "id", "value"))
```

**EDIT:**

problem was, `ForEach` LINQ method which reurns a `void` and your `SelectList()` HTML helper method expects a `IEnumerable<T>`. make small change like below in your view page

Change the list first separately

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "My Stunning Page";
    Model.MyList.Where(s => s.value == "1").ToList().ForEach(s => s.value = "January");
}
```

use it in control

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.months, new SelectList(Model.MyList, "id", "value"))
```

Comment: @SmitPatel, post the error message in text after removing that `}` from end

Comment: @SmitPatel, mind checking the edited answer again if it helps.