# Sum the repeated string list values and merge as one using linq in .net

Tags: vb.net, sum

The below code I tried to sum up the string value with the list values, it happens, but other values are not shown in return. I need to sum the values and other value should be returned to the object using linq in vb.net.

My code:

```vb
Dim lstrTaxValue As String = "YQ$40"
Dim lstaValues As New List(Of String)
lstaValues.Add("YQ$10")
lstaValues.Add("TQ$3")
lstaValues.Add("PQ$8")
lstaValues.Add("YQ$10")
lstaValues.Add("TQ$3")
lstaValues.Add("AQ$5")

Dim lobjTValues = (From lstr In lstaValues
    From lval In lstrTaxValue.Split(" ")
    Where (lstr.Split("$")(0) = CStr(lval).Split("$")(0))
    Select (CStr(lval).Split("$")(0) & "$" & (CDbl(CStr(lval).Split("$")(1)) + CDbl(lstr.Split("$")(1))))).ToList()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To quote Jon Skeet...

[Change some value inside the List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986776/change-some-value-inside-the-listt)

In comments...

Why do you want to use lambda expressions? The foreach code works fine and is simple. LINQ is for querying data, not mutating it. – Jon Skeet

Your objective does not seem to lend itself to Linq.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim lstrTaxValue As String = "YQ$40"
    Dim lstaValues As New List(Of String)
    lstaValues.Add("YQ$10")
    lstaValues.Add("TQ$3")
    lstaValues.Add("PQ$8")
    lstaValues.Add("YQ$10")
    lstaValues.Add("TQ$3")
    lstaValues.Add("AQ$5")
    Dim TaxValue = lstrTaxValue.Split("$"c)
    For i = 0 To lstaValues.Count - 1
        If lstaValues(i).Split("$"c)(0) = TaxValue(0) Then
            lstaValues(i) = TaxValue(0) & "$" & CStr(CDbl(lstaValues(i).Split("$"c)(1)) + CDbl(TaxValue(1)))
        End If
    Next
    For Each s In lstaValues
        Debug.Print(s)
    Next
End Sub
```

Result:

> YQ$50
>
> TQ$3
>
> PQ$8
>
> YQ$50
>
> TQ$3
>
> AQ$5